# Problem with Backtrader after installing ibpy2

Tags: python, ibpy, backtrader

Backtrader worked fine for backtesting, but after installing:

*pip install ibpy2*

there would be an error:

[image]

This problem really annoy since it just appeared in one of my systems.
I've uninstalled python and used anaconda, but the problem does not solve.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried every thing, at last I reinstated windows and it solved.

Answer (score 0):

`pip install wheel`

I had a same problem. Based on your file named `forex.py`, I assume you are trying to follow these tutorials from:

- [Part Time Larry](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZOohpUDdqKQ)
- [Daniel Rodriguez](https://medium.com/@danjrod/interactive-brokers-in-python-with-backtrader-23dea376b2fc)

In my case, I solved with `pip install wheel` in pipenv virtual environment.

Explanation:

- What is the error: Because the IbPy2 is written in Python2 and it's not running on proper Python version. Please read this answer for detail. [Python 2 and Python 3.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55076970/3354907)
- Why does it occur: When you create a virtual environment with `pipenv`, there is no `wheel` installed. Pipenv installs without `wheel` and the message is like this: `Using legacy 'setup.py install' for IbPy2, since package 'wheel' is not installed.` And then it was recognized as the code written in Python2.
- How to solve: Install `wheel` first with `pip install wheel`. And then install `IbPy2` with `pip install IbPy2`, then it will be properly installed and recognized as Python3 code. So you will not see the Python2 syntax error anymore.