# What is the right way to import IbPy2 and backtrader?

Tags: trading, backtrader

Hi i am having trouble importing backtrader and IbPy2. When i pip install both and when i run **import backtrader** in my python shell i get the following error:

i pip installed these:

> pip install https://github.com/blampe/IbPy/archive/master.zip

> pip install backtrader

The error i encountered:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File ~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py:3369 in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)

  Input In [3] in <cell line: 1>
    import backtrader as bt

  File ~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/backtrader/__init__.py:62 in <module>
    from .cerebro import *

  File ~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/backtrader/cerebro.py:35 in <module>
    from .brokers import BackBroker

  File ~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/backtrader/brokers/__init__.py:30 in <module>
    from .ibbroker import IBBroker

  File ~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/backtrader/brokers/ibbroker.py:30 in <module>
    import ib.ext.Order

  File ~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/ib/ext/Order.py:9 in <module>
    from ib.lib import Double, Integer

  File ~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/ib/lib/__init__.py:239
    except (socket.error, ), ex:
                           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

The specs of my machine are:

- macbook air m1
- jupyterlabs
- anaconda

I think i pretty much narrowed the problem down to IbPy2's fault. Whenever i import backtrader with no IbPy2 installed it works fine. But soon as IbPy2 is installed using the above pip command i encounter this error.

Any help is appreciated and would make my week I have been stuck for days! Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

`pip install wheel`

Explanation:

- What is the error: It is a python2 syntax error because it runs on different version of python. Please read this answer for detail. [Python 2 and Python 3.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55076970/3354907)
- Why does it occur: Because there is no `wheel` installed, especially when you create a virtual environment with `pipenv`. Pipenv or pip installs `IbPy2` without `wheel` and the message is like this: `Using legacy 'setup.py install' for IbPy2, since package 'wheel' is not installed.` And then it was recognized as the code written in Python2.
- How to solve: Install `wheel` first with `pip install wheel`. And then install `IbPy2` with `pip install IbPy2`, then it will be properly installed and recognized as Python3 code. So you will not see the Python2 syntax error anymore.

Comment: awesome, thanks for the tip. Will try it out.

Answer (score 0):

You can download the source code and run `setup.py build`, then `setup.py install`. You can see from the source code of `setup.py` as below; ideally, it will convert the

```py
try:  # Python 3
    print("python 3...")
    from distutils.command.build_py import build_py_2to3 as build_py
except ImportError:  # Python 2
    print("python2...")
    from distutils.command.build_py import build_py
```

Comment: I’ve made an [edit] to improve your formatting, but it appears that you didn’t complete your second sentence. Can you [edit] your answer to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, I solved it by converting the `__init__.py` file in the ib folder to python3.

Step 1: `cd .../lib/python3.9/site-packages/ib/lib`,

Step 2: `2to3 -w __init__.py`

This should hopefully solve your issue.